# Overriding GetOutPutCacheProviderName() in global.asax

Tags: asp.net, .net, caching

When overriding the function: `GetOutPutCacheProviderName()` in global.asax as below:

```
public override string GetOutputCacheProviderName(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.Path.EndsWith("Default.aspx"))
                return "FuleCacheProvider";
            else
            return base.GetOutputCacheProviderName(context);
        }
```

I don't know what exact value is returned by the else statement ? Is it: "in-memory"  as per the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.web.httpapplication.getoutputcacheprovidername.aspx)? I googled but can't find the implementation of `base.GetOutPutCacheProviderName()`.

If exact value returned by else statement can be provided, that will be great!

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation returns [OutputCache.DefaultProviderName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/SV-SE/library/system.web.caching.outputcache.defaultprovidername%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which is "AspNetInternalProvider" unless one is configured.